# Obtener duración de la ruta critica con macros en Ms Project

Tags: vba, macros

Cordial saludo.

Estoy desarrollando una macro en VBA en MS Project, la cual recorre las tareas y verifica si es o no critica, si lo és, suma su duración a una variable acumulativa.  Hasta aquí en teoria Excelente, pero al ejecutar el código me está retornado un valor excesivo (adjunto captura), para un cronograma de 195 días laborales (236 días calendario)

[image: captura de duración de ruta critica calculada]

Inicialmente la variable acumulativa Duracion era de tipo entero, pero al ejecutar la macro me generó inconvenientes, por lo tanto la declare nuevamente como long...pero ahora, me arroja la cantidad de 1540,5333.

Cantidad que he intentado convertir a horas y días pero las cantidades resultantes no me generan confianza, como al transformarlo en días indica que la duración de la ruta critica es 1,0698... días.

Podría alguien indicarme si estoy haciendo bien al usar tarea.duration para la duración de la tarea critica, o debo usar otra.  Si no es este el problema, duration indica que me retorna en días pero por qué el resultado no concuerda con el cronograma a mi parecer?

Agradezco sus valiosas colaboraciones a mi consulta.

```
Sub ObtenerDuracionRutaCritica()
    Dim Tarea As task

    ' Recorrer todas las tareas del proyecto
    For Each Tarea In ActiveProject.Tasks
        ' Verificar si la tarea está en la ruta crítica
        If Tarea.Critical = True And Tarea.Summary = False Then
            ' Obtener la duración de la tarea en días
            Dim duracion As Long 'Integer
            duracion = duracion + Tarea.Duration
            Debug.Print "Duración de la tarea " & Tarea.Name & ": " & duracion & " días"
        End If
    Next Tarea
    MsgBox "Duración de la ruta critica en días es " & ((duracion / 60)  / 60) / 24
End Sub
```

Edición 27/06/2023
Revisé nuevamente el código y funciona excelente, solo que en la división lo tomé como si estuviese recibiendo segundos; por ello se debe eliminar una división sobre 60, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
MsgBox "Duración de la ruta critica en días es " & ((duracion / 60)  / 24)
```